# The scope of custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have defined my helper function in Helper:

```
module CarsHelper

  def my_helper
    ...
  end

end
```

But I can neither used it(my_helper) in my `CarsController` nor in `Car` model, is it so that the custom helper can only be used in View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helpers are normally for views. But you can include them in your controllers as well. Just add

```
helper :cars
```

to your controller. ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper))

Models are out of scope for helpers. Use class or instance methods in there instead.

Answer (score 1):

The new way to use view helpers in controllers is to use:

`helpers.[helpername]`

See [this](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/26/rails-add-helpers-method-to-ease-usage-of-helper-modules-in-controllers.html) for more.